# how to use tokenNotExpired in angular 8

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement the angular jwt tokens, for that, I have found this module in one tutorial, but they are using angular4, they are using

```
     tokenNotExpired
```

which is importing from :

```
     import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
```

but I am using

```
    @auth0/angular-jwt
```

which is the latest version of  angular2-jwt, but I am not finding this module "tokenNotExpired" in "@auth0/angular-jwt" but I want to use that module, how can I do that.

I Installed "angular2-jwt" but there are dependencies errors are there how can I solve this.

Comment: Check this link https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-authentication-sample/blob/auth0-lock/src/common/auth.service.ts

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to go with @auth0, the JwtHelperService provides a "isTokenExpired" method, that sounds like a replacement for that "tokenNotExpired".